# Could not load type HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute after updating to Asp.Net MVC 4 RTM

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I'm working on a Single Page Application originally on ASP.Net MVC 4 Beta and EF 4.3.1.  I updated all of the NuGet packages for MVC 4 and EF 5.  Now whenever I make a call to an ApiController or DbDataController I get the following exception:

Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

```
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
```

According to the MVC 4 release notes, HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute has been removed, not that I was using it explicitly anyway.

> Per controller configuration: ASP.NET Web API controllers can be attributed with a custom attribute that implements IControllerConfiguration to setup their own formatters, action  selector and parameter binders. The HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute has been removed.
>   [MVC 4 Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253817)

My question is what could be trying to load this type at this point?

**Edit:** I'm thinking right now that this is because the SPA bits have not been updated since the MVC 4 Beta, and there are controller configuration attributes in there.

Comment: Same problem here, i wanted to use the DbDataController . If you find a solution feel free to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Per controller configuration: ASP.NET Web API controllers can be attributed with a custom attribute that implements IControllerConfiguration to setup their own formatters, action selector and parameter binders. The HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute has been removed. MVC 4 Release Notes

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's been removed.  You actually copied from my question, so I had read that before.  The thing is, I never used the attribute to begin with.  What I'm wondering is what is trying to load one now?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have older versions of System.Web.Http in your GAC. I believe in Beta version we GACed the dlls, hence you are seeing this problem...if you un-Gac this older dll, you shouldn't see this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem as the writer of this question, but i cant find the dll in my gac so thats not it..