# SInglePageApplication - DbDataController and HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute error

Tags: .net-framework-version, single-page-application

I am trying to work through the example from Steve Sandersons SPA video.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159

Much like the fellow in this question - [Could not load type HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute after updating to Asp.Net MVC 4 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150082/could-not-load-type-httpcontrollerconfigurationattribute-after-updating-to-asp-n) - My version does work with ApiController, but I need either DbDataController or LinqToEntitiesController, however during runtime both cause the exception below:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute' from
 assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I'm not explicitly using HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute. Here is my code.

```
namespace MvcApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class DataServiceController : DbDataController<MSEnterpriseEntities> 
    {
        public IQueryable<MS_Substations> GetUtilities()
        {
            return DbContext.MS_Substations.OrderBy(x => x.SubId);
        }

        public void InsertUtility(MS_Substations utility) { InsertEntity(utility); }
        public void DeleteUtility(MS_Substations utility) { DeleteEntity(utility); }
        public void UpdateUtility(MS_Substations utility) { UpdateEntity(utility); }

    }
}
```

I know HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute has been removed from System.Web.Http - I Don't know how to fix the problem though.

What exactly (for dummies version) do I need to do to fix this problem?